# Copy partitions from multiple drives to new larger drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have 2 750GB SATA hard drives that look like this:

[image]

If at all possible, I would like to copy all 6 partitions onto a new 2TB SATA drive. For bonus points, can I expand the partitions to fill up the rest of the 2TB drive?

Windows tools would be preferable. I don't boot Windows off of either of the 750GB drives currently installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easeus Partition Manager](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/) (Home Edition is free) has a [partition-copy](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/partition-copy.htm) function that allows you to select the source and destination partitions and choose how to handle the excess if the destination is larger (in your case, you would expand it as much as you like):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a combo of [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) (or another partitioner) and [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org). Gparted is available on most Linux live-cds, and clonezilla is available as an iso to create a live-cd.

Use gparted to create the target NTFS & ext4 partitions on the 2TB drive, and clonezilla in expert mode to clone the partitions to the new drive.

For expanding the partitions... you can create them at the desired size with gparted. When doing this, align the boundaries to "MB", and I suggest creating them in multiples of 1024MB. So if you want a 340GB partition, it will be 340 x 1024MB.

Since you'll be working with disk partitions, you might want to keep [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) handy in case anything goes wrong. It's available pre-installed on several rescue cds, or in the repos for most Linux distros, so you can install it to a live session if needed.

Comment: Those are okay, but he’s looking for Windows programs.

Comment: I can't recommend any Windows tools atm because I'm not current with any. However, I tested the above in a vbox test vm, and the process worked. If you're familiar with current Windows-only tools that fit OP's preferences, please post an answer.

Comment: Done. Single-malt it is. `;-)`

Comment: I _really_ wish there wasn't a 5 minute edit window on comments, so I could re-establish the context... oh well.

Comment: Very good. I don't mind using gparted and clonezilla, but Easeus sounds a bit easier. I'll keep this in mind though for future usage.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search came up with this.

http://www.extend-partition.com/resource/copy-partition.html

I've never used it so YMMV.  And yes, once the partitions are on the new drive they can be extended.  In windows 7 it's just a right click.  In Vista you'll need to use the command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the above tools will do the job, but because you have 6 partitions and all are primary, you may have to put at least 3 of them into extended partitions. The limit for primary partitions is still 4.